# The centralizer and normalizer of products of (Spin(n) $\times \dots$) in U(m)

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-groups, spin-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}$

Consider the [spin group $\Spin(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group) and the [unitary group $\U(16)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group).

Below I specify a *specfic* way to embed $(\Spin(6)\times \Spin(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2 \subset \U(16)$:

1. First we can easily embed the spin group $\Spin(10)\subset \U(16)$. Here we choose the $\mathbf{16}$-dimensional spinor representation of $\Spin(10)$ to be also the $\mathbf{16}$-dimensional fundamental representation of $\U(16)$. Thus, the data for the representation:
   $\mathbf{16}$ in $\Spin(10)$ as $\mathbf{16}$ in $\U(16)$
   gives us an action of $\Spin(10)$ and $\U(16)$ on the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^{16}$.
2. Then, we can easily embed $(\Spin(6)\times \Spin(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2 \subset \Spin(10) \subset \U(16)$. The mod $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factor means that the center $Z(\Spin(6))=Z(\SU(4))=\mathbb{Z}_2$ is identified with the *diagonal* $\mathbb{Z}_2$ subgroup of the center $Z(\Spin(4))=Z(\SU(2)\times \SU(2))=\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Here we denote:

- the irreducible spinor representation of $\Spin(6)$ as ${\mathbf 4}$
  (which is also the fundamental representation of $\SU(4)$).
- the complex-conjugated representation (of ${\mathbf 4}$) as $\overline{\mathbf 4}$.
- Also $\Spin(4)=\SU(2)\times \SU(2)$, where we concern the fundamental representation of each SU(2).

Then, the data for the following representation gives us an action of $(\Spin(6)\times \Spin(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2$ on $\mathbb{C}^{16}$, which further gives an embedding of $(\Spin(6)\times \Spin(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2$ into $\U(16)$:
$$\text{$({\mathbf 4},{\mathbf 2},{\mathbf 1}) \oplus (\overline{\mathbf 4}, 
 {\mathbf 1}, {\mathbf 2})$ in $(\Spin(6)\times \Spin(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a decomposition of $\mathbf{16}$ in $\U(16)$}.$$

### Question

1). Then my question is about the [*centralizer* and *normalizer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) of this $$(\Spin(6)\times \Spin(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2  \subset \U(16),$$
which certainly depends on the embedding that I provided above. My suspicion is that other than some $\U(1)$ factors, there could be additional discrete finite groups.

2). Another subtle issue is that given the same set of representation $({\mathbf 4},{\mathbf 2},{\mathbf 1}) \oplus (\overline{\mathbf 4},  {\mathbf 1}, {\mathbf 2})$,
it is not only a representation of $(\Spin(6)\times \Spin(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2$ but also a representation of $(\Spin(6)\times \Spin(4))$. Thus we can ask also the [*centralizer* and *normalizer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) of this embedding $$(\Spin(6)\times \Spin(4)) \subset \U(16)$$
other than the $(\Spin(6)\times \Spin(4))/\mathbb{Z}_2  \subset \U(16).$

Do we have the same or different answers of [*centralizer* and *normalizer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) for the Case 1) versus 2)?